# default+renderer error and null reference error of constructors in xamarin forms (android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, constructor, xamarin.forms

I have a list of image in my xaml on pcl project
when I test my app in my samsumg galaxy s5 mini device
I do this: I enter in the page of the list, then I press the back button on the action bar...I do it many times...then, it happens:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer from native handle 0x20e0001d (key_handle 0x42433c30).

or

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

the page that is running when I press the back button on the top bar and the error occurs **XAML** (PCL):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.ProdutosView"          
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.LayoutScripts"
         xmlns:interface="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Interface"
         xmlns:effect="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Effects"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         BackgroundImage="prodBackground.jpg"
         x:Name="ParentHost">

<ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Lista de produtos -->
            <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="listview_produtos" Margin="10,0,10,0" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ListView.Header>

                <!-- Observação -->
                <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="prod_stack_obser" IsVisible="False" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label x:Name="label_observ" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Margin="20,10,0,10" />
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="lapis" Source="lapis.png" IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="20"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                        <Grid Margin="20,0,20,20">
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="texturaCateg.png" BackgroundColor="{Binding FundoColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="produtos_stack_color" Spacing="10">

                                <StackLayout Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage FadeAnimationForCachedImages="True" DownsampleUseDipUnits="True" DownsampleHeight="60" HeightRequest="83" WidthRequest="130" Source="{Binding imagem}" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                                            <!--<ffimageloading:CachedImage.CacheKeyFactory>
                                                <interface:CustomCacheKeyFactory/>
                                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.CacheKeyFactory>-->
                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                        <!--HeightRequest="83" WidthRequest="100"-->
                                        <!--DownsampleHeight="83"-->
                                        <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Text="R$" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Text="{Binding valor}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="30"/>
                                            </StackLayout>-->

                                </StackLayout>

                                        <!--nome-->
                                    <Label Text="{Binding nome}" Margin="0,10,0,10" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                                </StackLayout>
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding observacao}" Opacity="1" FontSize="Small" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Footer>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid x:Name="prod_rl_fundo" >
                    <Grid.Margin>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                                 iOS="20,0,20,0"
                                 Android="20,10,20,10"/>
                    </Grid.Margin>
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="prod_acomp_img" Source="texturaCateg.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                        <!--Acompanhamentos-->
                    <StackLayout x:Name="stack_acompanhamentos" Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                        <Grid x:Name="prod_acompanhamentos_title" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.2"/>
                            <Label x:Name="produtos_acomp_title" Text="+ Dois Acompanhamentos" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Margin="20,20,20,20" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                <BoxView HeightRequest="50"></BoxView>
                </StackLayout>

            </ListView.Footer>

            </ListView>

            <!--Rodapé Grid-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="rodape.png" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Row="0"/>

            <!--Escrito Rodapé-->
            <StackLayout StyleId="rodapemenu" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   Margin ="5,5,5,5" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label
                   FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="Você está em:"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="White"/>

                <StackLayout.Effects>
                    <effect:SafeAreaPaddingEffect />
                </StackLayout.Effects>

                <Label FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="loja"
                   x:Name="prod_lbl_lojaprox"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource laranjacolor}"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

**C# of that**

```
using FFImageLoading;
using FFImageLoading.Forms;
using neoFly_Montana.Api;
using neoFly_Montana.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace neoFly_Montana.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProdutosView : ContentPage
{
    List<Produtos> lstProdutos = new List<Produtos>();
    Categorias categEscolhida;
    public Color FundoColor { get { return fundoColor; } }
    public Color TextColor { get { return textColor; } }
    Color fundoColor;
    Color textColor;
    string lojaProx;
    string codLoja;

    public ProdutosView(string codLoja, Object categEscolhida, object produtos, string lojaProx)
    {

        this.codLoja = codLoja;
        this.categEscolhida = new Categorias();
        this.categEscolhida = (Categorias)categEscolhida;
        lstProdutos = (List<Produtos>)produtos;
        fundoColor = Color.FromHex(this.categEscolhida.corFundo);
        textColor = Color.FromHex(this.categEscolhida.corTexto);

        this.Title = this.categEscolhida.nome;

        //TrataImagens();

        InitializeComponent();

        if (lojaProx != null)
        {
            this.lojaProx = lojaProx;
            prod_lbl_lojaprox.Text = lojaProx;
        }

        PopulaListView();

        //if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
        //{
        //    this.Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        //}
    }

    void TrataImagens()
    {
        foreach (var item in lstProdutos)
        {
            if (item.imagem != null && item.imagem.Trim() != "")
            {

                int initIndex = item.imagem.IndexOf(',');
                 string u = item.imagem.Substring(initIndex+1);
                try
                {
                    var bytes= Convert.FromBase64String(item.imagem);
                    item.imagem = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                  //  item.imagem = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var ss = e.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = (ListView)sender;
        list.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    void PopulaListView()
    {

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        Grid grid_acompanhamentos = new Grid
        {
           // BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            RowSpacing = 0,
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10),
            ColumnSpacing = 0,

        };

        //CachedImage prod_acomp_img = new CachedImage
        //{
        //    Source = "texturaCateg.png",
        //    Aspect = Aspect.Fill,
        //    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(this.categEscolhida.corFundo)
        //};

        //produtos
        listview_produtos.ItemsSource = lstProdutos;

        //observação
        if (categEscolhida.observacao != null && categEscolhida.observacao.Trim() != "") {
            label_observ.Text = categEscolhida.observacao;
            prod_stack_obser.IsVisible = true;
            lapis.IsVisible = true;
        }

        //acompanhamentos
        if (categEscolhida.acompanhamentos == null || categEscolhida.acompanhamentos.Count() == 0)
        {
             stack_acompanhamentos.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //prod_acompanhamentos_title.BackgroundColor = fundoColor;
            prod_acomp_img.BackgroundColor = fundoColor;
            produtos_acomp_title.TextColor = textColor;

            foreach (var item in categEscolhida.acompanhamentos)
            {
                StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();
                stack.Margin =  new Thickness (0,10,0,10);
                stack.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
                //stack.BackgroundColor = Color.Orange;
                stack.Spacing = 0;

                stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.nome, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, TextColor = textColor, HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) });

                if (item.observacao != null)
                    stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.observacao, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, TextColor = textColor, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) });
                else
                    stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = " ", TextColor = textColor, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) });


                grid_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(stack, column, row);

                if (column == 0)
                {
                    column = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    column = 0;
                    row++;
                }
            }
            stack_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(grid_acompanhamentos);
            //produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(grid_acompanhamentos,
            //    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            //    {
            //        return (parent.Width / 2) - (grid_acompanhamentos.Width / 2);
            //    }),
            //    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            //    {
            //        return (parent.Height / 2) - (grid_acompanhamentos.Height / 2);
            //    })
            //);


            //produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(prod_acomp_img, Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
            //    return parent.X;
            //}), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
            //    return parent.Y;
            //}), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
            //    return parent.Width;
            //}), Constraint.RelativeToView(grid_acompanhamentos, (parent, sibling) => {
            //    var teste =   sibling.Height;
            //    return teste;
            //}));

            //UpdateConstraintsBasedOnWidth(produtos_rl_acompanhamentos, grid_acompanhamentos);
           // produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.RaiseChild(grid_acompanhamentos);
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateConstraintsBasedOnWidth(Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout layout, Xamarin.Forms.View view)
    {
        view.PropertyChanged += (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Width") { layout.ForceLayout(); }
        };

        view.PropertyChanged += (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Height") { layout.ForceLayout(); }
        };
    }
}
}
```

The Previous page That the page above should back to when the error occurs
**XAML** (PCL)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.CategoriasView"
         xmlns:effect="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Effects"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         Title="Cardápio">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="familiaBackground.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill"/>

        <!--Categ grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="9.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="gridtextura" RowSpacing="20" BindingContext="{Binding nome}" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

            <!--Rodapé Grid-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Image Source="rodape.png" 
                   Aspect="Fill"
                   Grid.Row="0"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                <!--Escrito Rodapé-->
                <StackLayout StyleId="rodapemenu" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <StackLayout.Effects>
                        <effect:SafeAreaPaddingEffect />
                    </StackLayout.Effects>

                    <Label
                   FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="Você está em:"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="White"/>

                    <Label FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="loja"
                   x:Name="categorias_lbl_ljproxima"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource laranjacolor}"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />

                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using FFImageLoading.Forms;
using neoFly_Montana.Api;
using neoFly_Montana.Model;
using neoFly_Montana.PopUp;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace neoFly_Montana.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CategoriasView : ContentPage
{
    ActivityIndicator indicator;

    string codigoLoja;
    List<Categorias> lstCategorias;

    List<Produtos> lstProdutos = new List<Produtos>();
    List<Acompanhamento> lstAcompanhamentos;

    Categorias categoriaEscolhida;

    string observacao;

    string codCategoria;

    string lojaProx;

    LoadingPopUp loading;

    public CategoriasView(string codigoLoja, string lojaProx, object lstCategorias)
    {
        this.codigoLoja = codigoLoja;
        this.lojaProx = lojaProx;
        //this.codigoLoja = "162";
        this.lstCategorias = (List<Categorias>)lstCategorias;
        InitializeComponent();
        categorias_lbl_ljproxima.Text = lojaProx;
        CriaTela();
    }

    void CriaLoading()
    {
        LoadingPopUp loading = new LoadingPopUp("Carregando...", Color.Brown);
        PopupNavigation.PushAsync(loading, false);
    }

    private void CriaTela()
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        gridtextura.RowSpacing = 5;
        gridtextura.ColumnSpacing = 15;

        lstCategorias = lstCategorias.OrderBy(o => o.nome).ToList();

        foreach (var item in lstCategorias)
        {
            Grid GridContent = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            var textura = new CachedImage();
            textura.Source = "texturaCateg";
            textura.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.Aspect = Aspect.Fill;

            GridContent.BindingContext = item;

            Grid boxColorView = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                //InputTransparent = true,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            boxColorView.Children.Add(new StackLayout { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(item.corFundo), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 1);
            boxColorView.Children.Add(textura, 0, 1);

            //  boxColorView.Children.Add(new BoxView { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 0);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(boxColorView, column, row);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(GridContent, column, row);

            //Qual categoria foi escolhida?
            var CliqueCategoria = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            CliqueCategoria.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            CliqueCategoria.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                CriaLoading();
                var stacklayout = s as Grid;
                categoriaEscolhida = (Categorias)stacklayout.BindingContext;
                ChamaProdutos();
            };

            GridContent.GestureRecognizers.Add(CliqueCategoria);

            if (item.imagem != null && item.imagem != "")
            {
                int initIndex = item.imagem.IndexOf(',');
                string image = "";

                image = item.imagem.Substring(initIndex + 1);

                try
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image))), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, DownsampleHeight = 60 }, 0, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = "error.png", VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, DownsampleHeight = 50, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 50 }, 0, 0);

                }
            }

            GridContent.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.nome, TextColor = Color.FromHex(item.corTexto), FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)), FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation }, 0, 1);

            if (column == 0)
            {
                column = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }

        }

    }

    async Task ChamaProdutos()
    {
        await CallingProdutosAsync();
        await CallingAcompanhamentosAsync();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.ProdutosView(codigoLoja, categoriaEscolhida, lstProdutos, lojaProx), true);

        PopupNavigation.PopAsync();

        if (lstProdutos == null)
            DisplayAlert("Ops", "Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.", "Ok");

    }

    //carregamento de dados para a tela de produtos
    async Task CallingProdutosAsync()
    {
        lstProdutos = await Webservice.GetProdutosAsync(codigoLoja, categoriaEscolhida.idCategoria);
    }

    //este pode estar zerado
    async Task CallingAcompanhamentosAsync()
    {
        categoriaEscolhida.acompanhamentos = new List<Acompanhamento>();
        categoriaEscolhida.acompanhamentos = await Webservice.GetAcompanhamentoAsync(codigoLoja, categoriaEscolhida.idCategoria);
    }
}
}
```

I am asking me if it is not a debug mode error only. I am testing it now...
---update ----
in release mode it's happening :(

Comment: The responses of this old question brought to me a new problem in the same point

Comment: Got it, sorry. I'll take a read and try to get rid of the gross content by referring the original thread that brought you here and then I'll retract the duplicate flag. I've noticed no answer was accepted over there, it looked the same to me on first seen.

Comment: No problem friend. :)